# Spring integration Splitter task execution

Tags: java, spring-integration, splitter

I'm working on a Spring Integration application.

I have an inbound channel adapter that read a directory
Then a splitter that split the File into lines
Finally an udp outbound channel adapter that sends the lines

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter prevent-duplicates="false"
          id="filesIn" directory="file:input" channel="inputFiles" />

<int:splitter  input-channel="inputFiles" output-channel="udpChannel_11111"
         expression="T(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils).lineIterator(payload)" />

<!-- Define UDP outbound channel -->
<int:channel id="udpChannel_11111" />
<int-ip:udp-outbound-channel-adapter channel="udpChannel_11111"
        host="192.168.0.1" port="11111" />
```

I would like to send a line every one second

I can do this by define my own splitter and wait 1s each time I read a line, but I would like to know if it's possible to do it in the xml file to be as simple as possible.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the messages in a `QueueChannel` and use a poller to send once a second.

The UDP channel adapter doesn't currently support a poller, but you can use a bridge...

```
<int:splitter  input-channel="inputFiles" output-channel="udpChannel_11111"
     expression="T(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils).lineIterator(payload)" />

<int:channel id="toBridge">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>

<int:bridge input-channel="toBridge" output-channel="udpChannel_11111">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="1000" max-messages-per-poll="1" />
</int:bridge>
```

Bear in mind, though, that the file will quickly be loaded into the queue channel and you may have memory issues if it's very large.